# AWS ec2-authorize security group error "Unable to find group"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, ec2-api-tools

I've tried the following command

```
    ec2-authorize default -P icmp -t -1:-1 -o 'Monitoring Servers'
```

I've verified that it's a group using ec2-describe-security-groups

```
   "GroupName": "Monitoring Servers",
   "UserId": "WITHHELD",
   "GroupId": "WITHHELD"
```

I've tried the following permutations of this command:

```
    ec2-authorize default -P icmp -t -1:-1 --region us-east-1 -o "Monitoring Servers"
    ec2-authorize default -P icmp -t -1:-1 --region us-east-1 -o 'Monitoring Servers' -u WITHHELD
```

And still I get the same error:

```
    Client.InvalidGroup.NotFound: Unable to find group 'Monitoring Servers'
```

Comment: I think you can try the security group id (starts with sg) instead of the name. If you are using VPC, it appears that you need to use the group id.

Comment: Not using a VPC and tried the following  ec2-authorize default -P icmp -t -1:-1 --region us-east-1 -o 'sg-WITHHELD'
Client.InvalidGroup.NotFound: The security group 'sg-WITHHELD' does not exist

Comment: Are you sure your security group is in us-east-1? DO you have the `EC2_URL` env var set?

Comment: I'm full admin on the ec2 account, I can change other settings, I'm not sure how else to verify my keys, I also did a ec2-describe-groups   --region us-east-1 and Monitoring Servers came up in the list.  Is there another way to verify this? it is in the Virginia DC

Comment: I don't see a reason by this isn't working. Unless it has something to do with quoting the string. Can you pass the security group id again without quotes?

Comment: Same error without quotes.

Comment: The only case I've observed that this does not work is when the security groups are in different regions. Is it so in your case?

Answer (score 2):

As talonx mentioned, this usually happens if there is a region discrepancy.

First, add --debug to the cmd to get more information

to fix the command, add the --region parameter

so you final command might look like:

```
ec2-authorize default -P icmp -t -1:-1 -o 'Monitoring Servers' --region eu-west-1 --debug
```